# USB hub keep changing ports

Tags: usb, usb-modem, sms

I have an external powered USB hub and I'm using `Gammu` to send some SMSs, but every time the daemon connect to one specific modem, it has the port changed. Gammu is able to send just one SMS and after that the port is changed.

I've already tried using:

```
/dev/ttyUSB3
/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:0b.0-usb-0:3.4.3:1.0-port0
```

Is there anything to do which will stop the ports to be changed or use any other fixed port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved after changing the power supply of the hub.